# REST API - You have sent us an Illegal URL or an improperly formatted request

Tags: rest-api, query

Something like this is not working with query API's. Any help ?

```
https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/query?q=SELECT id,name from Account where Name LIKE '%aa%'
```

Got the below responsee with

> 400 Bad Request
>
> You have sent us an Illegal URL or an improperly formatted request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to URL encode your percentage signs (`%`).

The encoded version of the percentage sign is `%25`, so your request becomes

```
https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/query?q=SELECT id,name from Account where Name LIKE '%25aa%25'
```